# Hide Empty Datatable PrimeFaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I work on glassfish 3.1 with Primefaces. And i need to hide a dataTable if she is empty for display a error message.

But i can't hide a DataTable in the view.

Anyone can give me an exemple for help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132679/hide-primefaces-datatable-no-records-found-while-loading-the-table-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use style attribute:

```
style="display:block;"
```

when data found or:

```
style= "display:none";
```

when data not found.

You can also use renderen attribute:

```
<p:dataTable rendered="#{bean.dataFound}"
```

Comment: @tomi it works but when `<p:datatable>` changed that is to say updated with `<p:ajax>` it do not hides the table! Is there a solution to that? Thanks beforehand?